# Bash pipeline output is diff between in groovy and in terminal

Tags: shell, groovy

exist "ex/try.groovy", i try:

```
println "ls -al |grep try".execute(null, new File("/home/roroco/Dropbox/jvs/ro-idea/ex")).text
```

it didn't output anything

but when i try following, it will output "try.groovy"

```
roroco@roroco ~/Dropbox/jvs/ro-idea/ex $ cd /home/roroco/Dropbox/jvs/ro-idea/ex;ls -al |grep try
-rw-r--r--  1 roroco roroco   95 Nov 17 17:28 try.groovy
```

**my question is** how to make groovy output is same with terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not use `|` here as it is handled by the shell.  either use `sh -c` to execute or pipe yourself.  See http://groovy.codehaus.org/Process+Management

```
def p = ['sh', '-c', 'ls /tmp | grep groovy'].execute()
p.waitFor()
println p.text
```

or

```
def p1 = 'ls /tmp'.execute()
def p2 = 'grep groovy'.execute()
p1 | p2
p2.waitFor()
println p2.text
```